# How can I redirect the home to a different php page with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

When I enter the url mysite/home it goes to a php page called register.php. Where can I specify that it goes to login.php instead? Thanks

Comment: It's explained here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Answer (score 0):

In `application/config/routes.php` look for `$route['default_controller']`

Set its value to the desired controller name you wish to used as default (only controller, no method). By default, users that go to your base url will be shown whatever is at `name_of_controller_you_chose/index`